# Retrieving data in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Very new to VB.NET so please go easy :) Im currently working on an old application and im wondering if you could help me retrieve the data more efficiently. The below code works fine but everytime a new application variable is added it will need to be amended e.g dim groupthree, dim groupfour etc etc

```
Dim GroupOne As New Organisation(Application("testVar1"))
            Dim GroupTwo As New Organisation(Application("testVar2"))
            ddlGroups.AddDropDownListItem(GroupOne.Title, GroupOne.OrganisationID)
            ddlGroups.AddDropDownListItem(GroupTwo.Title, GroupTwo.OrganisationID)
            GroupOne = Nothing
            GroupTwo = Nothing
```

Basically im wondering if someone could suggest a better way to retrieve the variable data (which are in a DB table). I was thinking about using a list but so far i have had no luck trying to implement it

Many thanks

Paul

Comment: Rather vague.  What is `ddlGroups`, is this Winforms?  It might be that a List<T> as a DataSource would simplify things.

Comment: Is the organization information stored in the database as well? If so, why not use a query to populate the dropdown. If not, why not?

Comment: its win form yeah and when im i would like to populate a drop down list (ddlGroups) with application variables that are stored in a db. the name of the application variables are called testVar1, testVar2 etc.

Comment: Does the db get updated automatically when a new organization is added? And do you have any way to query the db for new variables?

Comment: hello, yeah i can query the db to see the variables that are in there. My original thinking was to name the variables the same and then create a list of the organisations. but i  cant get the list to work

Basically there is a column called value which is associated with an organisation. i need to retrieve each org value and then loop through and fetch back the data about that organistaion.

Difficult to explain sorry if it makes no sense

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something like the follwoing if the application variable were calle dthe same in the db but although there are two instances it only shows one in the dropdown list

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Organisation)
            Dim Group As New Organisation(Application("testVar1"))
            myList.Add(Group)
            For Each Item In myList
                ddlGroup.AddDropDownListItem(Group.Title, Group.OrganisationID)
                Group = Nothing
            Next
```

Cheers 
Paul